# Display image in new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net

I display the image thumbnail on datalist as:
[image]

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlistImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                        BorderColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <%--<img id="imgImageHtml" height="83px" width="150px" src="<%Eval("img_tb") %>" alt="Image not displyed" runat="server" />--%>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                 <asp:Image ID="imgnewspaper" style="float:right; margin:5px; margin-left:10px; border:2px solid #BAB9BE;" Width="90px" Height="95px" runat="server" OnClick="MyPicture_Click"  AlternateText='<%# Eval("newspaperName") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("img_tb") %>' Autopostback="true" />                 
                 </a>
                 </br>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pageNumber") %>' Font-Bold="true"
                            Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#336699" Width="100%"/>                            
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top" />    
    </asp:DataList>
```

Now I want to show the thumbnail big image on new tab.
How can I do???

Comment: What do you mean by *new tab*.?

Comment: means next window dude :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what you are doing and what it needs to be..?

Comment: you have to set **href** to full image. It can't be empty. Btw, i recommend you ASP.NET MVC. I've been using it for 6 months (earlier i worked as you in regular asp.net), and it's much easier than regular ASP.NET...
See me example in edited post below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you try to do, what are you using, what did you mean by *new tab* (new web browser tab?)

May be just:

```
<a href="yourImg.jpg" target="_blank"> 
    <img src='yourImgSmall.jpg' alt='some thumbnail' />
</a>
```

?

**EDIT :**

In RAZOR you can do for example:

```
foreach (var i in Directory.GetFiles(galleryPath).Select(Path.GetFileName)){

 <a href="/Content/images/@i" target="_blank"> 
   <img src='/Content/images/thumbnail/@i' alt='some thumbnail' />
 </a>


}
```

of course assuming that thumbnail has the same name as full image.

Comment: yes exactly what I want thanks but I am showing images dynamically from database based on query. Now I want to open image in new tab. How I give the image id, either by Eval() method or by any other technique there??